# Rights to documents sent on your behalf by an insurance company

Tags: california, insurance

I recently had my insurance company file subrogation against a government entity for the recovery of my deductible (and presumably their expended cost) after my vehicle was damaged on government property. My insurance company recently let me know that they were giving up on the subrogation claim against the government, and that if I wanted to recover my deductible I would need to pursue that myself.

So, I requested that they send me all the correspondence (which I understand is letters and emails from my discussions with them) between the government and the insurance company. However, they are claiming that they cannot provide that information to me, stating that I don't have a right do that correspondence.

So the question is, do I have a right to that information and are they obligated to provide that to me if I request it? It seems to me like I should have a right to it, since they were acting on my behalf.

I glanced around this site and didn't see any questions that relate to this, and I'm only assuming this is the correct site to post it, migrations or links are welcome, as always.